# EF Code first: Mapping of entities to existing database with intermediate table

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

This is a sample scenario. I have an existing database consisting of tables as below;

**Orders**, with field *OrderId* (PK, int)

**Products**, with fields *ProductId* (PK, int), *PriceId* (FK, int)

**OrdersProducts**, with fields *OrderProductId* (PK, int), *OrderId* (FK, int), *ProductId* (FK, int), *OrderingStatus* (int)

**Price** with field *PriceId* (PK, int)

All PKs are identity.

My Entities are;

```
public class Order
{
 [Key]
 public int OrderId { get; set; }
 public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
 [Key]
 public int ProductId { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public int OrderingStatus { get; set; }

 public virtual Price Price { get; set;}

}

public class Price
{
 [Key]
 public int PriceId { get; set;}

}
```

And here are my mappings;
Order;

```
  HasMany<Product>(x => x.Products)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {
      m.MapLeftKey("OrderId");
      m.MapRightKey("ProductId");
      m.ToTable("OrdersProducts", "dbo");
    });
```

Product;

```
Map(m =>
  {
    m.Properties(p => new
    {
      p.Name
    });
    m.ToTable("Products", "dbo");
  });

  Map(m =>
  {
    m.Properties(p => new
    {
      p.OrderingStatus
    });

    m.ToTable("OrdersProducts", "dbo");
  });

  HasRequired<Price>(x => x.Price)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("PriceId"));
```

Price;

```
  ToTable("Prices", "dbo");
```

I can't get this right with my mappings in the context, is there anyone that can help me in the right direction.

I am actually having two kinds of trouble here, first the mapping of OrderingStatus to my intermediate table, second I have trouble connecting my tables, ie 'Schema specified is not valid. Errors: ... error 0019: Each property name in i a type must be unique. Property name ''OrdersProductsId" was already defined.'

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping will not work - you can't map OrderingStatus to your Prodcut because it is not in the same table and it is not related by one-to-one relation to the Product. It is in separate table with one-to-many relation. You must expose OrdersProducts as separate entity because your junction table contains additional properties which you want to use:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductOrder> ProductOrders { get; set; }
}

public calss ProductOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderProductId { get; set; }
    public int OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Order { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Price Price { get; set;}
}

public class Price
{
    [Key]
    public int PriceId { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see it clearly now, realizing what has been my problem from the beginning.